# Use apt directly vs apt-*?

Tags: apt, package-management

I just found that there is a **apt** command that you can use directly:

```
 $sudo apt 
 apt 1.0.1ubuntu2 for amd64 compiled on Apr 10 2014 13:03:39
 Usage: apt [options] command

 CLI for apt.
 Basic commands: 
  list - list packages based on package names
  search - search in package descriptions
  show - show package details
  update - update list of available packages
  install - install packages
  remove  - remove packages
  upgrade - upgrade the system by installing/upgrading packages
  full-upgrade - upgrade the system by removing/installing/upgrading packages
  edit-sources - edit the source information file
```

With similar syntax to `apt-get`. And it offers some coloring in the CLI interface. So I want to know if there are some major difference between `apt` and `apt-*` commands? Why do people seem to post commands as `apt-get install` and `apt-cache search` when they don' t need the additional options `apt-*` commands provide, while `apt` is shorter with all the similar functionality with additional coloring, and in my opinion, better output format? Is it only habit?

I see in the manual pages that `apt` is for end-users while other low-level commands are for scripts. So why is everyone posting those low-level commands instead of the more user-friendly high level command?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The reason not many people recommend the simpler apt tool is because it's new. It wasn't in Ubuntu until the 14.04 release a week ago.

For most interactive uses it is equivalent but easier to use and looks nicer.

Comment: Awesome, I did not know that existed :-)

Comment: And you can [enable a progress bar](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/04/how-to-enable-apt-terminal-progress-bar) which is pretty cool and handy.

Answer (score 3):

I think this [apt official blog](https://mvogt.wordpress.com/2014/04/04/apt-1-0/) can explain everything.

> APT 1.0 was released on the 1. April 2014! The first APT version was announced on the 1. April exactly 16 years ago.
>
> The big news for this version is that we **included a new “apt” binary that combines the most commonly used commands from apt-get and apt-cache.** The commands are the same as their apt-get/apt-cache counterparts but with slightly different configuration options.